# how to rewrite urls in nextjs in dynamic routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am working on blogging website similar to medium.com and my folder structure is

```
pages\
    blog\
        [blog].js
    user\
        [username]\
            index.js
            [...catheverything].js
```

And what i want is

```
1) "mysite.com/@username"   --> load "user/username/index.js"   #this is working
2) "mysite.com/@username/catch-everything"  --> load "user/username/catch-everything"  #not working
```

**This is next.config.js file with rewrite function**

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/@:username",
        destination: "/user/:username",
      },
      {
        source: "/:slug",
        destination: "/post/:slug",
      },
    ];
  },
```

What would be my source and destination for this logic---> any help developers and thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean something like: `{ source: "/@:username/:slug", destination: "/user/:username/:slug" }`?